# Deeply nested form containing a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I saw the railscast on using deeply nested forms to make a survey:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=asciicast

How would you construct something similar in Rails to actually /take/ the survey, instead of just construct it for display in text?  How would you make a deeply nested form containing a survey form the user fills out?

Answer (score 2):

Couple things to consider:
Use fields_for (this is to construct child form).
Use nested_form to keep building child forms (n amount) - https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form