# Rails: ajax submit form to an action with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a part of the **show** view of the **exercise** model:

```
<div id="smoke_screen" style="min-height:100px">

    <% question =  @exercise.random_question %>
    <b class="question"><%= question.name %></b>

    <ul>
        <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
            <li><%= answer.content %></li>

        <% end %>
    </ul>

</div>
```

And it looks like this in the browser:

[image]

@answer and @question are nested models of exercise (exercise has_many questions, question has_many answers) and this is all viewed from the show view of the exercise model.

I'm trying to add a radio button to each answer and make an ajax call to an action i'll create named "save_answer". This action will receive both the question and answer objects, save the answer and return another question that will replace the #smoke_screen using ajax.

I'm new to rails, tried plenty of things with `form_to` with the attribute `:remote => true` without success. I will appreciate any direction on how to approach this

Comment: you need to use javascript for this

Comment: @IonutHulub that will be great but how? say i make a js.erb partial how will i render it?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax?autoplay=true this will probably help you

Comment: I asked a similar thing here, and also haven't found the tutorials helpful in figuring it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112741/deeply-nested-form-containing-a-nested-form